# MessageBox while compiling a C# WPF projects

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm receiving tons of Message Boxes while compiling a C# WPF project.
The project compiles neatly in my jobmates' PC, so I guess it's something in my Visual Studio settings.

Here the screenshots:

[image]

Please note that the Output is set on Diagnostic Level and shows no message:

[image]

PS: the program starts correctly after all the messages.

**EDIT**

Using [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) I managed to know who's the owner of the message boxes: LC.exe.

Comment: Have a look what extensions are installed and perhaps disable some?

Comment: Does the text or part of it show up in the project?

Comment: Are you building only the source project or building the test projects as well?

Comment: As pointed out by @Euphoric make search in your entire solution for "characters of second string".  See if anything pops up

Comment: No, there are no strings like that. As written in the question my jobmates compile without these messages.

Comment: Search for "MessageBox.Show" then. That string could be built on runtime...

Comment: Any chance, do you have any pre-build or post-build events configured for any of the projects being built?

Comment: Disable all extensions you have currently installed and try to build it again.

Comment: Nothing even with disabling al extensions.

Comment: 1) If there is another tool that is configured in the pre/post build event then that can show these message boxes during build.

Comment: 2) If there are test cases which are configured to be automatically executed after build and has message boxes... even that can show

Comment: @Sisir there are no test projects. I've just downloaded the project from source control.

Comment: Considering it works fine on other computers, suggestions of test projects and build events would not apply.   Extensions would as they are computer-specific and can intercept any event

Comment: What culture is your OS?  Friends?

Comment: You could prank someone by adding a .rsp file on their system. That'd add default switches to msbuild that'd do stuff every time they compiled.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-response-files?view=vs-2019

Comment: Our computer is set on EN-US culture and it's the same for every jobmate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the question, using the Microsoft's tool Process Explorer I've found that the MessageBoxes belong to .NET LicenceBuilder (LC.exe), this pointed me to the right direction looking for all of the 3rd part libs in the project, discovering a mismatch.